# jQuery datepicker restricts selectable year

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have two datepickers which only return years (i.e. 2014/2015). Datepicker 56 must be equal to or greater than datepicker55, which in one resepect the below code achieves. Datepicker56 when selected can be equal to or greater than datepicker55 however if I change datepicker55 to 2011/2012 then select datepicker56 to amend my year as being 2011/2012 it won't let me, it's first selectable year sticks at 2015. Datepicker56 can be selected on its own also. However if 55 is selected and then removed 56 again gets stuck on 2015 and won't let any previous years be selected. Is there a way to solve these issues?

```
$("#datepicker55").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy",
    onSelect: function(d) {
        $(this).val((parseInt(d) - 1) + '/' + d);
        var date1 = $('#datepicker55').datepicker('getDate');
        var date = new Date(Date.parse(date1));
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        var newDate = date.toDateString();
        newDate = new Date(Date.parse(newDate));
        $('#datepicker56').datepicker("option", "minDate", newDate);

    },
    viewMode: "years",
    changeYear: true,
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});

$("#datepicker56").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy",
    onSelect: function(d) {
        $(this).val((parseInt(d) - 1) + '/' + d);
    },
    viewMode: "years",
    changeYear: true,
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if 55 is selected and then **removed**" ? How do you "remove" it ?

Comment: one option might be to literally `destroy` the 2nd datepicker and then re-initialize it again.

Comment: @pistou, by remove I mean just to delete the value from the box that it resides in, by simply clicking on it and deleting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Datepicker API doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate), `null` is the default value for `minDate`

```
$("#datepicker55").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "") { // you deleted the value from it
        $("#datepicker56").datepicker("option", "minDate", null);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks pistou. Although I wasn't looking to delete the value from 56, I just wanted to reset the calendar value upon reselection, but this works for what I need.