# jQuery datepicker fault, year is pushed ahead and restricted

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I had previously asked this question [jQuery datepicker restricts selectable year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549050/jquery-datepicker-restricts-selectable-year).

The issue I am having now is that I had to change some of my datepickers to reflect the financial year in which my client works. This means that on or after 1st April then the year should change to 2016/2017. Therefore I changed my code to that which can be seen below.

If I use this code with a datepicker that can only have a year selected (datepicker 54) and a normal datepicker then it works fine, however if I combine two datepickers that only allow years to be selected then datepicker55 jumps ahead to July 2021. If I change minDateToSet and maxDateToSet to null then it loses its financial year restrictions and validation.

Any ideas on why this is and how to solve it?

```
$("#datepicker54").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "mm/yy",
  onSelect: function(d) {
    var selectedCalendarYear = parseInt(d.substring(3, 7));
    var selectedMonth = parseInt(d.substring(0, 2));
    var startYear = null;
    var endYear = null;
    if (selectedMonth < 4) {
      startYear = selectedCalendarYear - 1;
      endYear = selectedCalendarYear;
    } else {
      startYear = selectedCalendarYear;
      endYear = selectedCalendarYear + 1;
    }

    $(this).val(startYear + "/" + endYear);
    var minDateToSet = "01/04/" + startYear;
    var maxDateToSet = "31/03/" + endYear;
    $("#datepicker55").datepicker("option", "minDate", minDateToSet); //added null instead of minDateToSet and maxDateToSet
    $("#datepicker55").datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxDateToSet);

  },
  viewMode: "years",
  changeYear: true,
  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I needed to use an alternative approach as I couldn't code the datepickers to work as I wanted. Thus I created a database table, containing the following columns, YearID, DisplayText (which contains the values of the dropdown list i.e. 2015/2016), StartDate (i.e. 01/04/2015 in the format dd/mm/yyyy) and EndDate (31/03/2016 format dd/mm/yyyy).

I then brought this into my MVC model and rewrote my html helpers which you can see below.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EstimatedOnsiteYear, "Estimated Onsite Year", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
      <div class="col-md-1">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EstimatedOnsiteYear, (IEnumerable
        <SelectListItem>)ViewBag.YearTable, "Please Select") 
       @*new { @class = "datepicker55", id = "datepicker55" })*@
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EstimatedOnsiteYear)
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EstimatedCompletionYear, "Estimated Completion Year", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
      <div class="col-md-1">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EstimatedCompletionYear, (IEnumerable
        <SelectListItem>)ViewBag.YearTable, "Please Select") 
        @*new { @class = "datepicker56", id = "datepicker56" })*@ 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EstimatedCompletionYear)
      </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see I have changed my HTML helpers to `DropDownListFor` and attached an `IEnumerable <SelectListItem>`along with a ViewBag which is pushed through from my controller.

**Controller code**

```
public JsonResult FilterYearSelector(int id)
    {
         // Fix circular reference errors
         db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        //return all years with id greater than id parameter
        //change >= to reflect what you need the proceeding year to be
         IEnumerable<YearTable> yearTable = db.YearTables.Where(a => a.YearID >= id).ToList();
         return Json(yearTable, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In my controller code I'm pointing towards my YearTable which was added to my model and returning the result as Json, AllowGet is used to retrieve the information as a GET request. This also applies to the Ajax Jquery method which can be seen below.

I placed the Ajax code at the bottom of my view, in my case this is the create view. The comments in my Json code explain what processes are occurring. But the main purpose is to filter one dropdown list based on another through emptying the second dropdown list and rebuilding it.

```
<script>

            $(document).ready(function (){

                $("#EstimatedOnsiteYear").change(function () { // Attach to the change handler of element with id of EstimatedOnsiteYear (primary DDL)

                    var id = $("select#EstimatedOnsiteYear").val();

                    if (id != null || id != "")
                    {
                        $.ajax({

                            type: 'GET',

                            url: '@Url.Action("FilterYearSelector")', // The JsonResult function in controller

                            datatype: 'json',

                            data: { id: id }, // pass in the value of the primary DDL select

                            success: function (years) {
                                // Clear element with id of EstimatedCompletionYear (secondary DDL)
                                $("#EstimatedCompletionYear").empty();
                                $("#EstimatedCompletionYear").append("<option value=''>Please Select</option>");

                                // yearSelector contains the JSON formatted list
                                // passed from the controller
                                $.each(years, function (i, year) {
                                    $("#EstimatedCompletionYear").append('<option value="'
                                        + year.YearID + '">'
                                        + year.DisplayText + '</option>');
                                });
                            },

                            error: function (ex) {
                                alert('An error has occured' + ex);
                            }
                        });
                   }
                    return false;
                });
</script>
```